# Can dynamic casting be done in a generic function instead of overloading?

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I am wondering if instead of doing something like this:

```
void attrSetValue(Entity* entity, int index, std::string value)
{
  dynamic_cast<stringAttribute*>(entity->attribute[index])->value = value;
}
void attrSetValue(Entity* entity, int index, int value) 
{
  dynamic_cast<intAttribute*>(entity->attribute[index])->value = value;
}
```

Can a generic function be written to accept whatever type is passed and cast it correctly to save the data?  Something like a template.  I can see that a template itself is problematic, seeing that it isn't doing the same thing on different types, although it is almost doing the same thing on different types.  It is just the dynamic_cast type that changes.  To make the question easier, is there a way of simplifying the code by getting rid of the overloading?  Does the overloading impact the performance in any way?

To explain a bit what's going on above, seeing that this is only a very small section of the code, the attributes of the entity's can be of any type (int, double, string, char, bool, etc..) - thus using inheritance with a virtual function to get the attribute values to have different types.  Theses attributes are added to a vector on the Entity struct/class.  E.g.

```
std::vector<attribute*> attributes;
```

Comment: Can you replace `intAttribute` by a template class `Attribute<int>`?

Comment: Overloading does not impact run-time performance - which function to call is determined at compile time.

Comment: @KerrekSB If not, we can have `Attribute<int>::type = intAttribute`, `Attribute<std::string>::type = stringAttribute` etc. via template specialization and `typedef`. More ugly, more code, but possibly worth it if removing the `attrSetValue` overloads gets rid of enough duplication.

Comment: The attrSetValue looks fishy: You might have a look at boost::any: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html

Comment: @delnan: Yeah, I thought of that, but that would seem to be no simpler than the original... well, it'd provide a nice factorisation.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, it does remove the `attrSetValue` overloads, and possibly other generic code. But yes, it's not as nice as getting rid of all the `*Attribute` classes as well.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, I can replace intAttribute with a template class Attribute<int>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to do type mapping:

```
template <typename T> struct TypeMap;
template<> struct TypeMap<int> { typedef intAttribute type; };
template<> struct TypeMap<string> { typedef stringAttribute type; };

template <typename ValueT>
void attrSetValue(Entity* entity, int index, ValueT value)
{
  dynamic_cast<typename TypeMap<ValueT>::type*>(entity->attribute[index])->value = value;
}
```

Performance will be the same as your original code.  You can do this in a more fancy way using Boost MPL to do the type mapping, but it amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward:

First define a way of turning a value type (T) into an attribute type. In the simplest case, your attribute classes would be templates, so you would just have to write:

```
Attribute<T>
```

if your attribute classes cannot be written as templates for whatever reason, you just need to write a type-function to get the type for you:

```
template<typename T>
struct attribute_for;

template<>
struct attribute_for<int> { using type = intAttribute; };
template<>
struct attribute_for<std::string> { using type = stringAttribute; };

template<typename T>
using AttributeFor = typename attribute_for<T>::type;
```

Now make `attrSetValue` be a template function that uses that technique for turning the value type into the attribute type:

```
template<typename T>
void attrSetValue(Entity* entity, int index, T value) 
{
  dynamic_cast<AttributeFor<T>&>(
         entity->attribute[index]).value = std::move(value);
}
// OR
template<typename T>
void attrSetValue(Entity* entity, int index, T value) 
{
  dynamic_cast<Attribute<T>&>(
         entity->attribute[index]).value = std::move(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it solve your problem (assuming `Attribute` is base class of all, i.e. `intAttribute`,`stringAttribute` etc :

```
template<class T>
class Attribute
{   
   T value;
  public:
   void setValue(T val){
     value = val; 
   }
};


class intAttribute : public Attribute<int>{

   //other code
};


class stringAttribute : public Attribute<string>{

 //other code
};

template<class T>
void attrSetValue(Entity* entity, int index, T value)
{
  entity->attribute[index])->setValue( value); //no casting needed
}
```

Comment: Of course this assumes the `*Attribute` classes are all the same save for type, which isn't necessarily the case. Also, you might want to leave the `dynamic_cast` to show how one would use it.

Comment: @delnan, I did not understand your comments. Could you please clarify a little? thanks

Comment: First, this answer only works if there is a (sensible) generic `Attribute<T>` base class for `intAttribute`, `stringAttribute`, etc. -- if there is no such base class, more modifications are necessary. Second, as it may not be obvious to the asker or other readers, I think your example could be improved by showing how to do the `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Yes, I'm a bit confused by this answer..Is it not better to have your set and get functions as helper functions, outside of your inheritance scope?  I want to keep the attributes as light as possible.

Comment: @delnan, you are right, I should have explained in details. I have posted full code. I believe assuming all `*Attribute` classes inherit from `Attribute` is not harmful here, since they naturally express *IS-A* relationship, so it will lead to good design. Also no casting is needed.

Comment: @worker11811, ".Is it not better to have your set and get functions as helper functions, outside of your inheritance scope" -- could you plz clarify it? if you dont want to getter/setter, you can make the member `public`, as you did (though to me it is bad compared to getter/setter).

Comment: @RakibulHasan I can see what you are trying to do, but now if we have to add these to a vector, to hold the collection of attributes how would this be done?
I used the virtual functions so that an attribute can have more than one type of value (so the inherited part is purely to store the attribute value), but can be stored on the entity as an array of attributes:
`std::vector<attribute*> attributes;`